# Solving hyperbolic equation with parallelization in python by elucidating Mathematica algorithm

Tags: equation-solving, parallelization, implementation-details, python

So! I have what seems like a rather basic hyperbolic equation to be solved written in Mathematica, with an integer input ‘n’, for which I am seeking the First {x,y} Integer solution to satisfy the equation, equivalent to finding the first positive integer pair with the smallest ‘x’. Not all n have solutions however. Here is the Mathematica code:

n=69;

First[Solve[(2y-1)x+(y(y-1))/2==n&&x>0&&y>1,{x,y},Integers]]

Which yields the solution {x->9,y->4} nicely. So nicely in fact that I have no idea how to replicate its efficiency in my own naive Python code, which is vexing. ‘Solve’ in Mathematica feels to me like a black box, mysteriously opaque algorithm that eludes explanation. Note: In the Wolfram|Alpha solution for y given in the screenshot below with input n=69, what is in this case 553 under the square root always equals (8n + 1). Maybe something fancy is happening with Pell’s equation, but it’s unclear to me. In any case even solutions that you can attain for what seem to me relatively large input have their answers returned immediately, while my attempts to code something similar in python have floundered somewhat for large input.

That said, even Mathematica falls short of where I’d like to take it, which is for input ‘n’ of over 4000+ bits, but I suspect this may be limited by the fact that so far I’ve only either attempted it in Mathematica Cloud or a 2-Core system running on a 7-year old netbook, which begs the question firstly of whether this is something that automatically takes advantage of parallelization with Mathematica’s unknown algorithm or, given an expansion of the license to number of kernels allocated if it could be parallelized further and whether there is additional code needed to speed up the calculation that way. Hypothetically, were I to drop $4K on a 20-core Mac Studio, purchase a license to the 16-kernel expansion allocated by gridMathematica, and work some parallelization magic into the code could I somehow speed it up 10x as fast as I would on a 2-core system?

Ideally I’d like to understand and replicate the algorithm used for solving this function without necessarily being tied to Mathematica, though if that’s the only/best way I could, though that’s a more expensive proposition stemming from my inability to code it myself because my math acumen is somewhat lacking I suppose. Mathematica has a limit of I think 24 kernels at most though and parallelization in general has no particular limit if you can express it in something like python. I’m not as familiar with alternatives outside of some basic Mathematica as yet.

So I suppose I am really asking two questions: (1) How to optimize for fast output with parallelization of this equation’s solution for a first pair of {x,y} integers in Mathematica if I had the license for expansion of available kernels I’m considering, and (2) what the algorithm behind Mathematica’s solution is such that I could replicate its efficiency in my own non-proprietary python code with parallel processing, ideally with example code so I could hit the ground running since I am pretty new to this dimension of computational maths beyond single-core, assuming the algorithm is not locked to linear time-complexity.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since solving is equivalent to factoring $8n+1$, good luck doing it for 1200-digit integers. (Unless there's an $8n+1$ algorithm I don't know.) -- I don't believe `Solve` can be parallelized; about the only thing that could be parallelized is an exhaustive search, which search it will do in certain circumstances. I don't know if it parallelizes the search.

Comment: I have to say that I'm confused by the interest in this question. It primarily seems aimed at programming in Python: off topic. It is about implementing a solution that the current state of computational mathematics says is infeasible: off topic? It's asking about the internal implementation of `Solve` and how to parallelize it; a few know something about internals, a lot is unknown: off topic? The current anwers are for fun and don't address the real issues above (they stay within the realm of what is feasible) — that's ok, I don't mind the fun.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for answering the heart of my question. Although I use Python as a vehicle for replicating best algorithmic practices, finding what they are would (sometimes) involve learning from Mathematica if I could understand how it does some of these things so well, so I could learn instead of using a black box tool I don’t understand called ‘Solve’, but most of us aren’t that savvy. Not infeasible if you have the right algorithm to deal with large numbers in principal, but not with a brute force approach. I’ve found my solution without parallelization with some tinkering : ] Fun~ !

Comment: You're welcome :)  Have you seen [these notes on internals](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#23195)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution that seems to be as fast or sometimes faster than the `Solve` method. It will not be useful for 4000 bit numbers, but the implementation is transparent and perhaps there is room for improvement.

**Code.** Here is a version of your solution using `Solve`:

```
findxy1[n_]:=With[{s=Solve[(2y-1)x+(y(y-1))/2==n&&x>0&&y>1,{x,y},Integers]},
               If[s==={},{},First[MinimalBy[s[[;;,;;,2]],First]]]];
```

Here is a solution using `Divisors`:

```
allx[n_]:=Select[With[{p=Divisors[8*n+1]},
            (8*n+1-p^2)/(8*p)],And[IntegerQ[#],0<#<n]&];
findxy2[n_]:=With[{xs=allx[n]},
               If[xs==={},{},With[{x=Min[xs]},{x,(1-4*x+Sqrt[1+8*n+16*x^2])/2}]]];
```

**Check.**

```
Array[findxy1,5000]===Array[findxy2,5000]
(* True *)
```

**Timing.** For small `n` there is a big difference

```
First[AbsoluteTiming[Array[findxy1,5000]]]
(* 40 seconds *)
First[AbsoluteTiming[Array[findxy2,5000]]]
(* 0.15 seconds *)
```

For larger `n` they are similar

```
SeedRandom[1];
ns=RandomInteger[{1,2^150},100];

First[AbsoluteTiming[Map[findxy1,ns]]]
(* 23 seconds *)

First[AbsoluteTiming[Map[findxy2,ns]]]
(* 13 seconds *)
```

**Edit.** I think the solution can explicitly be described as follows: Let $q$ be the smallest divisor of $8n+1$ bigger than $\sqrt{8n+1}$. Define $p = (8n+1)/q$. Then $x = (q-p)/8$ is the solution, except when $q = 8n+1$, in which case no solution.

Answer (score 6):

Not fast at all, but it seems to work. Just posting this for fun. This simply increases `x` and lets `y` oscillate about the graph of the hyperbola until an integer solution is found. This could be made faster by providing suitable lower bounds for `x`.

```
n = 1024231231;
rhs = 2 n;
x = 0;
y = 2;

While[True,
  ++x;
  lhs = 2 (2 y - 1) x + (y (y - 1));
  While[lhs < rhs,
   ++y;
   lhs = 2 (2 y - 1) x + (y (y - 1));
   ];
  If[lhs == rhs,
   Break[];
   ];
  ++x;
  lhs = 2 (2 y - 1) x + (y (y - 1));
  While[lhs > rhs,
   --y;
   lhs = 2 (2 y - 1) x + (y (y - 1));
   ];
  If[lhs == rhs,
   Break[];
   ];
  ];

2 (2 y - 1) x + (y (y - 1)) == 2 n
```